# Can I set a default color for all texts in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm struggling to do something that I think ought to be simple in Highcharts. I want the background dark grey and all the axis labels, title, etc texts light gray.

I can almost accomplish this by adding a lot of "color" declarations, but ... that seems repetitive and I'm sure there's a better way.

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            // WHY CAN't I SET A GLOBAL "COLOR" HERE?
            backgroundColor: '#272b30'
        },
        title: {
            text: "Title Title",
            align: 'left',
            style: {
                // DEFINE IT ONCE FOR THE TITLE
                color: '#99aabb'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            // DEFINE AGAIN FOR LEGEND BORDER
            borderColor: '#99aabb',

            // AND FOR LEGEND ITEMS
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#99aabb'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"]                
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'axis label',
                style: {
                    // DEFINE ONE MORE FOR THE AXIS LABEL
                    color: '#99aabb'
                }
            }    
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Series',
            data: [61, 55, 67, 88, 59]
        }, {
            name: 'Other Series',
            data: [20, 15, 17, 22, 28]
        }, ]
    });
});
```

I am confident that I'm missing something super obvious here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define global variable, which will keep color, and then set theme with defined variable.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic/grid

*But you'll still have to explicitly theme each component to get the color from that variable.*

Answer (score 1):

You can color legend using `itemStyle`, for example:

```
legend: {
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#000000',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
```

See docs [Highchart Options Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemStyle)

Comment: Nod. I found that (probably while you were typing). So that's helpful, but I'm still setting the color over and over and over.

Comment: For chart you can define style, too. But it I didn't manage to get text changed overall. I mean, for example  `chart: {
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'monospace',
            color: "#f00"
        }

    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it programmatically... just a little function which will lighten base color for you:

```
function shadeColor(color, percent) {   
    var num = parseInt(color,16),
    amt = Math.round(2.55 * percent),
    R = (num >> 16) + amt,
    G = (num >> 8 & 0x00FF) + amt,
    B = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt;
    return (0x1000000 + (R<255?R<1?0:R:255)*0x10000 + (G<255?G<1?0:G:255)*0x100 + (B<255?B<1?0:B:255)).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```

then set and use the base color as variable

```
var baseColor = '272b30'
```

now you can dynamically can generate your skin.

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            // WHY CAN't I SET A GLOBAL "COLOR" HERE?
            backgroundColor: '#' + baseColor
        },
        title: {
            text: "Title Title",
            align: 'left',
            style: {
                // DEFINE IT ONCE FOR THE TITLE
                color: '#' + shadeColor(baseColor,70)
            }
        },
        legend: {
            // DEFINE AGAIN FOR LEGEND BORDER
            borderColor: '#' + shadeColor(baseColor,70),

            // AND FOR LEGEND ITEMS
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#' + shadeColor(baseColor,70)
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"]                
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'axis label',
                style: {
                    // DEFINE ONE MORE FOR THE AXIS LABEL
                    color: '#' + shadeColor(baseColor,70)
                }
            }    
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Series',
            data: [61, 55, 67, 88, 59]
        }, {
            name: 'Other Series',
            data: [20, 15, 17, 22, 28]
        }, ]
    });
});
```